# Django: Store gmt time in database table instead of local time

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-timezone

In my customer model I have two datetime fields for storing created and updated time.

```
datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
datetime_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I create a customer, Now it is storing the local time in the database, When I get this customer data through API, It is returning the datetime in gmt time. This is fine. But I want to save the gmt time in the database. I think storing local time in database is not a good practice.

Date settings in settings.py file is

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

I have already installed "pip install pytz" module and my database is postgresql.

Comment: Of course that is a good practice save in UTC. I recommend you that save your datetime in utc, and to convert it to your convenience in your views using  `pytz` or in your templates using `tz` tag

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is to save it in UTC format.

`USE_TZ = True` in your settings, Django stores date and time information in UTC in the database otherwise it will store naive date time

Answer (score 0):

You're rigth, the best practice is to save in UTC your datetime fields, and to convert it to your convenience in your views using `pytz` or in your templates using `tz` tag.

IE, you can use pytz to convert your datetime in an specific datetime in your views

```
import pytz

datetime_with_new_tz = object.created_at.astimezone(pytz.timezone(YOUR_LOCAL_TIMEZONE))`
```

if you want to convert the timezone in your template, you can use `tz`

```
{% load tz %}
{{object.created_at|timezone:YOUR_LOCAL_TIMEZONE}}
```